# Slight typo on application--should I mention it in interview?

Tags: interviewing, applications

I made a slight typo on a job application in describing some grad school classes. I meant to say I took two classes, one in Computer Technology and one in Information Management. But the typo made it sound like they were one class. I have a phone interview for that position tomorrow--should I mention that or not? Thank you.

---

I did mention this in an interview, but it turned out that the application was right and what I said in the interview was wrong. Another accidental mistake in a class name.

Comment: Can you specify the exact typo? (If it is in your resume, I do not think it is too sensitive information to be posted here).

Comment: Basically I took two grad school classes that I wanted to highlight--Computer Technology and Information Management. The application had  a place to highlight extra skills. But on the application I accidentally mistyped those words so they sounded like one class instead of two.

Answer (score 2):

> should I mention it in interview?

If that info is relevant to this particular job and is an important requirement for this position, then yes, you could mention it briefly in the interview.

Comment: It is important. It's a library job, and those were library science classes.